# what is event driven web server

Tags: webserver

I want to understand basics of Event Driven web server, I know one of them is Tornado, but any other information is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: why is this question inappropriate, that there's one close request?

Answer (score 32):

There's a nice analogy of this described here:

http://daverecycles.tumblr.com/post/3104767110/explain-event-driven-web-servers-to-your-grandma

Relevant text from the above link:

> Explain “Event-Driven” Web Servers to Your Grandma You’ve heard the
> term event-driven, event-based, or evented when it comes to web
> servers. Node.js is based on evented I/O. nginx is an asynchronous
> event-driven web server.
>
> But what does the term mean? Here’s an easy way to think about it.
>
> Let’s think of a web server as a pizza shop that needs to take orders
> over the phone (requests for web pages).
>
> **Traditional Web Server**
>
> The pizza shop hires operators (processes/threads) to take orders over
> the phone. Each operator has one phone line. After the operator is
> done taking the order, the operator keeps the customer on the line
> until the pizza (response web page) is done baking and then tells them
> it’s ready to pick up.
>
> So the pizza shop needs to hire as many operators as the number of
> pizzas that may be baked at once in order to serve all customers who
> call in.
>
> **Event-Driven Web Server**
>
> The pizza shop only hires one operator, but has trained the operator
> to hang up after taking the order, and call the customer back when the
> pizza is ready to be picked up.
>
> Now one operator can serve many customers.

Comment: +1 Perfect example! [This](http://www.slideshare.net/simon/evented-io-based-web-servers-explained-using-bunnies) is great too.

Comment: The link is dead or not opening via protected proxy. If possible, please add the relevant text here.

Answer (score 19):

A web server needs to handle concurrent connections. There are many ways to do this, some of them are:

- A process per connection.
- A process per connection, and have a pool of processes ready to use.
- A thread per connection.
- A thread per connection, and have a pool of threads ready to use.
- **A single process, handle every event (accepted connection, data available to read, can write to client, ...) on a callback.**
- Some combination of the above.
- ...

At the end, the distinction ends up being in how you store each connection state (explicitly in a context structure, implicitly in the stack, implicitly in a continuation, ...) and how you schedule between connections (let the OS scheduler do it, let the OS polling primitives do it, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Event-driven manner aims at resolving the C10K Problem. It turns the traditional 'push model' into a 'pull model' to create a non-blocking evented I/O. Simply put, the event-driven architecture avoid spawning additional threads and thread context switching overheads, and usually ends up with better performance and less resource consumption.

Some overview from a rails developer, also includes analogy:
http://odysseyonrails.com/articles/8

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.